# iPhone: Time Profile Instrument

Tags: iphone, instruments

Has any body good tutorial or description how to use Time Profile Instrument ?
All that I found is 
   http://blancer.com/tutorials/flex/78335/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in/

and

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments/

I understod that I should use "show obj - C only" option. But what about flags ? How to use them ? How to create them ? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You create flags by pressing `command` + `down` after you have drug the dotted line to the area you want to flag.