# What is the number percentage after code line means using Instrument?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, instruments

I have gone through following and most of the question posted on forum
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263783/iphone-time-profile-instrument)

I have run time profile for check application, on double click in the call stack it goes to the code, The code shows X% next to the line
What is that means? Is that value of time require for process code? Please refer images attached

[image: Show alert view]
[image: Dismiss alert view]

When call goes for show alert it shows (93.8)% and another image for dismissing alert it shows (100%)
What these value represent?

Comment: It's the amount of time spent on that particular line of code within that scope.

Answer (score 1):

It is the percentage of time spent running that line in that part of the program. The line listed 100% is the only thing that gets run in that method, so it takes 100% of the time.

Comment: oops, I didn't see that.  I fixed my answer.